# convert a 2d list to RDD[vector] or JavaRDD[vector] scala

Tags: scala, vector, type-conversion, rdd

I have a 2d list of integers and I would like to convert it to either RDD[vector] or JavaRDD[vector] in order to use the predict method of the SVM model in spark MLlib.
I have tried the following, in order to convert it to rdd. But it seems that this is not what I need.

```
 val tuppleSlides = encoded.iterator.sliding(10).toList
 val rdd = sc.parallelize(tuppleSlides)
```

Any ideas what is the command to convert it to the right type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use MLlib you will need an `RDD[LabeledPoint]`. Given your 2D list of data and some list of labels, you can create your `RDD[LabeledPoint]` like so:

```
scala> val labels = List(1.0, -1.0)
labels: List[Double] = List(1.0, -1.0)

scala> val myData = List(List(1d,2d), List(3d,4d))
myData: List[List[Double]] = List(List(1.0, 2.0), List(3.0, 4.0))

scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

scala> import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint

scala> val vectors = myData.map(x => Vectors.dense(x.toArray))
vectors: List[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector] = List([1.0,2.0], [3.0,4.0])

scala> val labPts = labels.zip(vectors).map{case (l, fV) => LabeledPoint(l, fV)}
labPts: List[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint] = List((1.0,[1.0,2.0]), (-1.0,[3.0,4.0]))

scala> val myRDD = sc.parallelize(labPts)
myRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:34
```

Comment: I just read this documentation about predict that's why I needed these types: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMModel .Do you have any hints about how to do it as a labeled point RDD?

Comment: Pretty straightforward: `val pos = LabeledPoint(1.0, Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0))`. First arg to `LabeledPoint` is the label, second arg is the feature vector.

Comment: And make sure you use the MlLib vector, not the Scala standard vector

Comment: @Kratos No problem, FYI: [please upvote and accept answers rather than using thank you comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Kratos I updated the answer to illustrate how to make the `RDD[LabeledPoint]`, please take a look to make sure it still deserves your upvote/acceptance

Comment: I figured it out following your instructions!
But thank you for taking the time to do that. It definitely deserves both ;)